# Migrate odoo javascript from v8 & v9 to v10

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

hay i want to do something with javascript in odoo v10 and when im searching i found what i need but in version 8 and copy it from v8 to 10 it gives me some error and i dont know how to fix it here is the code similar to what i want

```js
_.each(result,  function(res) {
setTimeout(function() {
    //If notification not already displayed, we add button and action on it
    if (!($.find(".eid_"+res.event_id)).length) {
        res.title = QWeb.render('notify_title', {'title': res.title, 'id' : res.event_id});
        res.message += QWeb.render("notify_footer");
        a = self.do_notify(res.title,res.message,true);
        a.element.find(".link2showed").on('click',function() {
            self.get_notif_box(this).find('.ui-notify-close').trigger("click");
            self.rpc("/calendar/notify_ack");
        });
    }
```

when i test this code first gives me the "a" is not defined so i put "var"
second it gives me error that "element" in a.element is undefined and when i console.log(a) in console print Undefined so i think that 
self.do_notify(res.title,res.message,true); returned with nothing 
so please can an one help HOW TO DO IT IN Odoo V10 ?????????//

Answer (score 0):

```
_.each(result,  function(res) {setTimeout(function() {
//If notification not already displayed, we add button and action on it
if (!($.find(".eid_"+res.event_id)).length) {
    res.title = QWeb.render('notify_title', {'title': res.title, 'id' : res.event_id});
    res.message += QWeb.render("notify_footer");
    a = self.do_notify(res.title,res.message,true);
    a.element.find(".link2showed").on('click',function() {
        self.get_notif_box(this).find('.ui-notify-close').trigger("click");
        self.rpc("/calendar/notify_ack");
    });
}});  });
```

Try this..

Comment: thanks so much but my problem was not in brackets it was coding and changing syntax from v8 to 10 and i solved this by changing      a.element.find(".link2showed").on('click',function() {
to a.$(".link2showed").on('click',function() {
and self.get_notif_box(this).find('.ui-notify-close').trigger("click");
to self.$('.o_close').trigger("click");
Thanks so much